# Efeito hover não funciona

Tags: html5, css3

Gostaria de fazer um efeito *hover* no meu formulario igual o desse site:

http://novaerateam.com.br/

Quando passa o mouse em cima aparece uma caixinha do lado não consigo fazer isso

```css
.corpo-1 ul li {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.corpo-1 ul {
  margin-top: 10%;
}
.contato-barra {
  width: 10%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #000;
  border: none;
}
input[type="text"] {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-family: Gabriola;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  outline: none;
}
#form-1:hover {
  display: block;
}
.teste1 {
  margin-left: 65%;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  color: #000;
  display: none;
}
select {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-family: Gabriola;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  outline: none;
}
textarea {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-family: Gabriola;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  outline: none;
}
#enviar {
  background-color: #000;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Gabriola;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}
#enviar:hover {
  background-color: #333;
}
```

```html
<div id="formulario">
  <form>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <input type="text" placeholder="  Digite seu nome" id="form-1">
        <p class="teste1">testeteste teste</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="text" placeholder="  Digite seu Email">
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="text" placeholder="  Digite seu Nickname">
      </li>
      <li>
        <select>
          <option value="the-elder" selected>--- Selecione um jogo ---</option>
          <option value="the-elder">The Elder Scrols Online</option>
          <option value="archage">ArcheAge</option>
          <option value="worlofwarcraft">World of War Craft</option>
          <option value="forsaken">Forsaken World</option>
          <option value="leagueoflegends">League of Legends</option>
          <option value="dota">Dota 2</option>
          <option value="smite">Smite</option>
          <option value="warface">Warface</option>
          <option value="cs">CS-GO</option>
          <option value="bf">Battle Field</option>
          <option value="cod">Call of Dutty</option>
        </select>
      </li>
      <li>
        <textarea placeholder="  Mensagem"></textarea>
      </li>
      <li>
        <button id="enviar">Enviar</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Você já tem algum código feito? Se sim, coloque na pergunta.

Comment: @EduardoSilva pronto amigo ta no post mais lembrando que nao faço ideia de como fazer isso criei uma classe teste para fazer um teste se vai mais nao funciona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ideia é bem simples:
Basta manter o elemento oculto até que haja a ação de **`:hover`** e/ou **`:focus`** no input. Um exemplo:

```css
.input-group p {
  display:none
}

.input-group input:focus + p,
.input-group input:hover + p {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<li class='input-group'>
  <input type='text' placeholder='email@foo.com' />
  <p>Insira seu email para contato</p>
</li>
```